# Rails check for params key presence and value defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to check if params is present with a key defined?

```
if(params.has_key?(:one) && params.has_key?(:two))
```

check if the key is present but the value can be also nil...

How can I check in a single line is I have two params with a defined key?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if (params.has_key?(:one) && params[:one].present?) && (params.has_key?(:two) && params[:two].present? )
```

Answer (score 1):

Too many conditions in one line, may I suggest doing this instead?

```
if params.has_key?(:one) || params.has_key?(:two)
  do_1 if params[:one].present?
  do_2 if params[:two].present?
end
```